# How can I return records with calendar dates based on day of the week?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema:

Schedules represent a schedule for a recurring event.

```
# Table name: schedules
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  start_date :date
#  end_date   :date
```

Days represent the WEEKdays of the schedule on which an activity occurs.

```
# Table name: days
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  schedule_id :integer
#  wday        :integer
```

TimeSlots represent the hours that an activity may occur at (may be many per day).

```
# Table name: time_slots
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  day_id       :integer
#  start_time   :time             not null
#  end_time     :time             not null
```

An example dataset, could be:

- 1 Schedule with start date 1st of June, and end date 30th of June
- 1 Day, width wday = 0 (activity happens every Monday in June)
- 2 TimeSlots. 1 with start_hour 8am and end_hour 11am. Another with start_hour 1pm and end_hour 3pm

Given the above example (represented in SQL below), I would like to return one record for EACH Monday in June, WITH their calendar date included.

June 2017 has 4 Mondays, so the above example would look something like:

```
 id | wday | calendar_date |
----+------+---------------+
  1 |    2 |    2017-06-05 |
  1 |    2 |    2017-06-12 |
  1 |    2 |    2017-06-19 |
  1 |    2 |    2017-06-26 |
```

Can anybody steer me in the right direction?

Setup PSQL below:

```
CREATE TABLE schedules (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    start_date date,
    end_date date);

CREATE TABLE days (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    schedule_id integer,
    wday integer);

CREATE TABLE time_slots (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    start_time time,
    end_time time,
    day_id integer);

INSERT INTO schedules (id, start_date, end_date) VALUES (1, '2017-06-01', '2017-06-30');
INSERT INTO days (id, schedule_id, wday) VALUES (1, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO time_slots (id, start_time, end_time, day_id) VALUES (1, '18:00', '19:00', 1);
```

Comment: you dont have to store day of week - you can `select extract(dow from now())`?..

Comment: I'm working on an existing codebase. The schema structure is already set up and in use, using the wday to represent  an activity on a given day in any given week.

Comment: firts day of week is sunday or monday?

Comment: In Postgresql Monday = 0

Comment: then why wday = 2?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when writing this question. should be 0

Answer (score 2):

```
select     s.id, wday, start_date + g calendar_date
from       schedules s
cross join generate_series(0, end_date - start_date) g
join       days d on d.schedule_id = s.id
where      extract(isodow from start_date + g) - 1 = wday
```

http://rextester.com/GTPQ53700

Notes:

- with [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) you can generate rows, where there is no data in the DB
- I assumed you want weeks to start on Monday (because it is represented by `0` in your tables). The closest to this is `ISODOW` in PostgreSQL, but that uses 1-7 for Monday-Sunday. (`DOW`, on the other hand, uses 0-6 for Sunday-Monday: so weeks starts on Sunday with `DOW`.)
- this won't actually look into `time_slots`. If you need that, add the following predicate to your `WHERE` clause:

  ```
  and exists(select 1 from time_slots t where t.day_id = d.id)
  ```